# Snowflake SQL → Column JSON values into table

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My TRR table is composed of JSON values in each row (I removed null rows from TRR), and I'd like to split these JSON rows into a table with corresponding columns

[TRR with JSON values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JqEl.png)

Each row can have multiple entries:
[expanding one row example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F703J.png)

What I need is the following (no need to keep the row number in the target table):

| (Row) | discount | id | points_text | points | src_trl_code | src_trl_id | trn_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (1) | 0 | 1113302 | TIERS_PTS: 1 | 0 | CCU_L_01 | 108 | 743156 |
| (2) | 0 | 1112948 | TIERS_PTS: 1 | 0 | CCU_L_01 | 108 | 743430 |
| (3) | 0 | 2552076 | NULL | 0 | CCU_L_01 | 108 | 402953 |
| (4) | 0 | 746255 | STATUS: 50 | 0 | CCU_L_01 | 659 | 503055 |
| (4) | 0 | 746254 | SMILE: 50 | 0 | CCU_L_01 | 108 | 503055 |
| (...) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT  array_construct( object_construct( 'discount', 0, 'ID', 
1113302, 'points', 0, 'points text', 'TIERS_PTS:1', 'secirlcode', 'CCU_L_01', 
'srcirlid', 108, 'TRN_ID', 743156 ) ,
object_construct( 'discount', 4, 'ID', 1114302, 'points', 1, 'points text', 
'TIERS_PTS:5', 'secirlcode', 'CCU_L_01', 'srcirlid', 168, 'TRN_ID', 743156 ) 
) YOUR_ARRAY )

SELECT 
  HI.VALUE:ID
, HI.VALUE:TRN_ID
, HI.VALUE:points
, HI.VALUE:"points text"
, HI.VALUE:secirlcode 
FROM 
   CTE
 , LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT=> YOUR_ARRAY) HI ;
```

Functions used:

- [LATERAL()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html)
- [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html)
- Using : for [GET_PATH()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_path.html)

Proof it works:

[image]

Same starting point :

[image]

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly for one row of my HRR table. Now how do you iterate over all lines of my TRR table so I can append all values to the HI table?

Comment: Um that code shouldn't really care how many rows do you have an error message or something ?  Also the lateral flatten function doco is pretty good.

Comment: The first part of your code, I use: WITH CTE AS ( SELECT array_construct(SELECT TRR from MyTable where TRR is not null order by Date) YOUR_ARRAY), for the rest I kept the same. Snowflake returns "Single-row subquery returns more than one row." What's Inside the array_construct() is what you can see in my first print screen in the description.

Comment: it seems to me the latteral flatten function is not able to iterate over the values of my table [check TRR with JSON values image]. I've tried different things such as aggregating rows with agg_cat, and iterating but nothing works...